# How to check username and password from database using HIbernate in spring MVC?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have made a login application using SPRING MVC with annotations. I am not 
being able to verify the username and password from the database, created in
phpmyadmin using Hibernate.

Below is my code

```
package Repository;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import LoginDao.LoginPojo;
import Repository.User;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class UserMain { 
    private static SessionFactory sf;
    public void setup() {
        try {
            sf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
                    .addPackage("com.registration.domain")
                    .addAnnotatedClass
            (User.class).buildSessionFactory();

            } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    void verifyUser(String usernm,String passwd)
    {
         Session session = sf.openSession();
          Transaction tx = null;
          try{
             tx = session.beginTransaction();
             List<?> lst = session.createQuery("FROM LoginPojo").list(); 
             for (Iterator<?> iterator = 
                               lst.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
                 LoginPojo lpojo = (LoginPojo) iterator.next(); 
                System.out.print("Username: " + lpojo.getUsernm()); 
                System.out.print(" Password: " + lpojo.getPasswd());                
                if(lpojo.getUsernm().equals(usernm)&& lpojo.getPasswd().equals(passwd))
                {
                    System.out.println("Correct username and password");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect username and password");
                }
             }
             tx.commit();
          }catch (HibernateException e) {
             if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
             e.printStackTrace(); 
          }finally {
             session.close(); 
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "not able". Also, you're doing it wrong: Spring should be handling the session handling and the transactions for you, declaratively. You shouldn't load all users into memory just to check the password of one of them: use a better query. And passwords should not be stored in clear text in a database. They should be salted and hashed with a strong crypto algorithm.

Comment: Tutorial you may find it useful: http://krams915.blogspot.com/2012/01/spring-security-31-implement_5023.html